# Advantages of a Binary Heap for a Priority Queue?

Tags: data-structures, heap, quicksort, priority-queue

It seems I'm missing something very simple: what are advantages of a Binary Heap for a Priority Queue comparing, say, with quick-sorted array of values? In both cases we keep values in an array, insert is O(logN), delete-max is O(1) in both cases. Initial construction out of a given array of elements is O(NlogN) in both cases, though the link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29 suggests faster Floyd's algorithm for the Binary Heap construction. But in case of a queue the elements are probably received one by one, so this advantage disappears. Also, merge seems to perform better for a Binary Heap.
So what are the reasons to prefer BH besides merge? Maybe my assumption is wrong, and BP is used only for studying purpose. I checked C++ docs, they mention "a heap" but of course it does not necessary means Binary heap.
Somewhat similar question: [When is it a bad idea to use a heap for a Priority Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025317/when-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-a-heap-for-a-priority-queue?rq=1)

Comment: Actually, a lot of questions here on SO do mention binary trees as a PQ implementation.

Comment: Another one comparing a heap and a binary tree: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637446/why-heap-is-better-than-binary-tree-to-represent-a-priority-queue?rq=1 
But none of the answers for that question are relevant here.

Comment: @templatetypedef Sorry I made a mistake: delete-max is O(logN) for BH, I meant find-max is O(1). I realized it after I read your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The major advantage of the binary heap is that you can add new values to it efficiently after initially constructing it. Suppose you want to back a priority queue with a sorted array. If all the values in the queue are known in advance, you can just sort the values, as you've mentioned. But what happens when you the want to add a new value to the priority queue? This might take time Θ(n) in the worst case because you'd have to shift down all the array elements to make space for the new element that you just added. On the other hand, insertion into a binary heap takes time O(log n), which is exponentially faster.

Another reason you'd use a heap over a sorted array is if you only need to dequeue a few elements. As you mentioned, sorting an array takes time O(n log n), but using clever algorithms you can build a heap in time O(n). If you need to build a priority queue and residue k elements from it, where k is unknown in advance, the runtime with a sorted array is O(n log n + k) and with a binary heap is O(n + k log n). For small k, the second algorithm is much faster.

Comment: Thanks! I would put another +1 for usage of Θ(n). 
I still have a question. I missed that shifting part when I asked the original question. But can shift be optimized for a sorted array? In this case only one contiguous block has to be shifted, as opposed to O(logN) exchange for a BH.

Comment: If you have an n-element array and need to insert an element into the middle of it, you'll need to shift n / 2 elements out of the way to make room for it even if the list is sorted. Unless you switch from using an array to some other data structure, there's no way to avoid paying this cost.